# scroll along with page when touch on iframe. (in Apple device it is not working)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, iframe, scroll, youtube-iframe-api

When I touch the iframe and scroll so It will scroll along with the page but I need to scroll only contain so what can I do (scrolling on Apple device is not working but in Android device, it working charmingly).

According to the Apple iOS mantra, it should be possible to scroll the contents of an IFRAME by dragging it with two fingers.

**iframe code**

```
/// Video URL split
var url = result[i].image_url; 
if(url.indexOf('?v=') > -1) {
  var split = result[i].image_url.split('?v=');
  var code = split[1].split('&');
  url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + code[0];
} else if(url.indexOf('/v/') > -1) {
    var split = result[i].image_url.split('/v/');
    // var code = split[0] + '/embed/' + split[1];
    url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + split[1];  
  }

html += "<iframe width='100%' height='500'  src='"+ url +"' allowfullscreen='' frameborder='0'></iframe>";
html += "</div>"
// html += "</div><div class='home-box-ttl'>" + result[i].title + "</div>"
} else {
html += "<div class='marquee_single'>"
html += "<a href='" + result[i].daily_pill_url + "'>";
console.log(result[i]);
html += "<img id='" +  result[i].op_ed_image_id + "' alt ='" +  $alt[i]  + "' title='" + $title[i] + "' width='100%' height='500' style='display:block' src='" + result[i].image_url + "'  >";
html += "</a></div>"
}
}
```